# Vue.js - Loading a global _variables.scss file

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, sass, vue-cli

Building a Vue app using `@vue/cli 3`. I am at a point where I need to integrate SCSS, haven't used SCSS with vue before so having some trouble.

My SCSS structure is pretty conventional:

- `_variables.scss` containing all my variables
- `_layout.scss` containing some layout related stuff
- `_componentX.scss` styles for componentX
- ...
- `_componentN.scss` styles for componentN
- `app.scss` import everything

I want break this up by removing the `component#.scss` imports from `app.scss` and instead putting those styles in the component's (SFC) style tags.

When I try this however, the component throws errors for unrecognized variables (even though `app.scss` is imported in `main.js`)

The workaround would essentially be importing `app.scss` in every component. Is this the way to go? (seems strange) or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That is the way to go, yes. Import everything that you use within your component.

Comment: Maybe you can use [sass-resources-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader) to do the imports.

Comment: @str that means all paths I use *within* app.scss and other .scss files can't be relative right? becuase the paths will be resolved relative to the component file and they could be in different locations. I have to use webpack aliases?

Comment: @user3690467 Usually you can use paths like `~@/a-directory/test.scss` but that depends on your build setup.